# GCP - For particular bucket make policy for access

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my GCP project, people have storage admin access. I want to restrict the person and give few members writing access in the GCP bucket. When I try to revoke the access it is saying cannot change access as it is inherited.

Any way to create custom access for a particular storage bucket in GCP. I have to make this for the AIRFLOW DAG bucket.

Answer (score 3):

Custom roles cannot be recognized upwards on the resource hierarchy. For example, a role created at the project level cannot be used at the folder or organization level.

Similarily, custom roles cannot be recognized laterally. For example, a custom role created at the project level cannot be used in bindings in another project even if they are in the same folder or organization.

To use a custom role in different projects or different folders, customers have to create/define the roles at the parent organization level. Note that currently, a custom role cannot be created at the folder level.

For more information on custom roles you can check the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#deleting-custom-role).